# Passing boolean parameter in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am wondering how do I pass a false value to my ruby script.

If I invoke:

```
ruby myscript.rb false
```

and then in my script if I say:

```
my_class.new(*ARGV)
or my_class.new(ARGV[0])
```

basically a string with value "false" gets passed. Clearly if I say

```
if(ARGV[0]){ do something} .. this gets executed even if value passed is false.
```

Can I change my function signature to auto-covert paramter to boolean ..so that I dont have to do

```
if(ARGV[0]=='true')
```

Comment: how do you expect your function to interpret non-boolean strings like `'foo'`?

Answer (score 10):

You need to evaluate the command-line argument. Anything passed on the command line is a string, that's all the command line knows about.

For example, you could monkey-patch String (untested):

```
class String
  def to_b
    self =~ /^(true|t|yes|y|1)$/i
  end
end
```

Or write a utility, or use the command-line option parser (long-term best bet), or...

Comment: Your regex would match 'untrue' :)~! So I recommend adding `^` at the front: `/^(true|t|yes|y|1)$/i`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you want to do more sophisticated commandline parsing with option switches, including Boolean ones, take a look at Ruby's built-in [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html).

Answer (score 3):

```rb
def to_b(string)
  case string
  when /^(true|t|yes|y|1)$/i then true
  when /^(false|f|no|n|0)$/i then false
  else raise "Cannot convert to boolean: #{string}"
  end
end
```

This is based on [Dave Newton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9235010/109618) with two differences:

1. More symmetry -- if you are explicit with tests on the 'true' test, I think you should also be symmetrical on the 'false' test.
2. Just say no to `/(monkey|duck) p(at|un)ching)/` key classes like `String`!

Answer (score 2):

You CANNOT pass objects from command line. Only object you can pass is a String. I guess at some point in your program you have to do:

```
if(ARGV[0]=='true')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a little string helper for converting a string to a bool; it adds a `.to_bool` method to strings. If the string is equal to `true` or `t` or `yes` or `y` or `1`, the result will be `true`; otherwise `false`.

```
class String
  def to_bool
    !!(self =~ /^(true|t|yes|y|1)$/i)
  end
end
```

Examples:

```
"aaa".to_bool #=> false
"t".to_bool #=> true
```